# What does return {__html : RawMarkup} means and how to call return value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
    var Comment = React.createClass({
        RawMarkup : function() {
            var RawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize:true});
            return {__html : RawMarkup};
        }
```

I am confused with the return. Does it return an object or a function?
When I use it in the Component I will do like this:

```
{this.RawMarkup}
```

and the result is :

> react.js:18893 Uncaught Invariant Violation: `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`.

`{this.RawMarkup()}` works. But I don't know what it really means.

Comment: `{__html : RawMarkup}` creates an object with property `__html`. Maybe a tutorial about basic JavaScript data types will be helpful? http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . Or are you confused that there is a method with name `RawMarkup`, which also uses a local variable `RawMarkup`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes, I am confused with the second , I thought , when I call the method in Component I should write like this : {this.RawMarkup} and the code above means I should write like this {this.RawMarkup()}